# Python For loop and range. What is my mistake

Tags: python

I am trying to return the list that function will take in. This is what I have got:

```
def boo_list(my_list):
    for i in range(0, len(my_list) - 1, 1):
        print(i)
```

If I call for the function:

```
boo_list([True, True, False])
```

It returns:

```
0 
1
```

Not

```
True
True
False
```

Where is the error in my logic?

Comment: to return and to print are two different things. Learn using proper term.

Comment: In fact you seem to ask for printing all the values from the list without doing any specific transformation of the values.

Comment: Note that range(N) goes, by default, from 0 to N-1; so you don't need to give it a zero start, nor a step, and you shouldn't substract 1 from the length of the array. I strongly encourage you to follow a good tutorial, the official one is quite good.

Comment: This is an OK question in the sense that you [showed us what you tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). However, we want to make it easy for others to find solutions to similar problems, *so please don't include things like "What is my mistake" in the title of your question.* After all, that's probably not what *you* were typing into Google when you were trying to find a solution to this problem before asking on here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, because you are dealing with the length and are printing the indices not the actual values.

Instead, do:

```
def boo_list(my_list):
    for i in my_list:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also use lambda function to print desire result.

```
>>boo_list = lambda x:x

>>boo_list([True,False,True])
```

output:

```
#Result : [True, False, True]
```